# How to highlight current argument in SLIME

Tags: emacs, slime

I am using sbcl with GNU Emacs 24.3.1 and the 2012-04-14 release of SLIME, on Arch Linux to write some Common Lisp code. When writing an expression, if I type, for example

```
(if
```

the minibuffer will display

```
(if TEST THEN &OPTIONAL ELSE)
```

Is there a mode or SLIME setting that can make the argument that I'm currently editing be highlighted in the minibuffer? For example, if I type

```
(if (> x y)
```

it would be great if

```
(if TEST *THEN* &OPTIONAL ELSE)
```

or something similar was displayed in the minibuffer.

Comment: Which Emacs and SLIME versions do you use? In Lispbox under Windows it seems to work out of the box.

Comment: Which documentation minor mode do you use? You can easily find that out by checkin the status line? There should be something like `(Lisp ElDoc ...)` or `(Lisp Autodoc ...)`.

Comment: @Alexey Added a few configuration details to the question. Regarding the documentation minor mode: I'm not using eldoc mode, and I don't think I have Lisp Autodoc installed (I did a C-h a for "autodoc" with no results). Also, here is what is displayed on my mode line - nothing regarding documentation:

`game.lisp    86% (115, 15)    (Lisp [? sbcl])`

Comment: How's SLIME configured in your emacs setup? Do you have something like `(slime-setup '(...))`?

Comment: @Alexey In my .emacs I have the following lines:
`(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/slime-2012-04-14/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange thing is that you have documentation in minibuffer with this configuration. Maybe your distribution also loads it from a different location.

Please try this config:

```lisp
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/slime-2012-04-14/")
(require 'slime)
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(slime-setup '(slime-autodoc))
```

It tells Emacs to load and use `slime-autodoc` module that displays documentation and in minibuffer and highlights it as you'd like it to be.

Maybe you'd also like to update to a more recent SLIME version (the current one in ELPA is 20130402).

Comment: Excellent. It took a bit of fiddling to get everything working properly but slime-autodoc is what I needed. Thanks!